# invalid column name in .net while using inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, entity-framework-5

I have a problem mapping a relationship
while reverse engineering in visual studio .net

I use inheritance:

```
public class Quiz : Component  
{
    public QuizQuestion rootQuestion { get; set; }
    public override String getType() { return "quiz"; }
}
```

the property `rootQuestion` is not specified in the motherclass, it only exists in the subclass

`Quiz` doesn't exist as a table in my sqlserver database(only the `QuizQuestions` and `Component` table exists in the database, (my teacher told me to do it like this for
the java part of this project).

But I want the subclass Quiz to have a property `rootQuestion` that refers to `quizRootQuestion` in my database. So here's what I did:

```
public class QuizMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<Quiz>        
{
    public QuizMapper()               
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.ComponentID);
        this.HasOptional(c => c.rootQuestion)
            .WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("quizRootQuestionID"));     

    }
}

public class QuizQuestionMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<QuizQuestion>
{
    public QuizQuestionMap()
    {
        // Properties
        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.HasKey(t => t.QuestionID);
        this.ToTable("QuizQuestions");
        this.Property(t => t.QuestionID).HasColumnName("questionID");
    }
}
```

I get this error when i'm trying to run in my browser:
**Invalid column name 'rootQuestion_QuestionID'.**

Tables in my database:

**Component:**

```
  componentId                 
  quizRootQuestionID          
  TypeId(=discriminator)
```

**QuizQuestions**

```
questionID                 
question
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: yeah, i use entity framework 5.
structure: a learning course has different components, 1 of these is 
a quiz

Answer (score 0):

You would get exactly this exception if you forgot to add the `QuizMapper` to the model builder configuration in `OnModelCreating` of your derived context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new QuizMapper());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new QuizQuestionMap());
}
```